# C# Sharepoint 2010 Alert List not found

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I´m trying to write an application to set Alerts on a list for all people that are already having minimum one alert in the sitecollection. I know how to get the user objects for all this users, but when I try to set the alert for each user there appears the problem. For some users there comes an SPException that says that the list is not existing. I looked in the user.Alerts propertie and there is a field Web, where the sitecollection name is at the users that dont work. It works only for the users that have the right web in there to access the list and set the alert. Does anyone know a workaround so that i can set alert for all the users that i want?
Here is the code I´m using to set the alerts:

```
SPAlert alert = user.Alerts.Add();
alert.AlertType = SPAlertType.List;
alert.EventType = SPEventType.Add;
Console.WriteLine(alertWeb.Url+" "+ alertingListName);
alert.List = alertWeb.Lists.TryGetList(alertingListName);
alert.AlertFrequency = SPAlertFrequency.Immediate;
alert.AlwaysNotify = false;
alert.Update(false);
```

Thanks in advance for helping me

I have solved the problem on myself now. I post the solution here so people who have the same problem can find it.
The problem was that in the User Object propertie user.alerts.web was the wrong web. I solved this problem by getting the user object not from the web.alerts collection but from the web.allusers collection, so that the right web stands in the propertie.